# Object of array of objects. Get the length of all values with the same property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, max

I have an object that looks like this:

```
    var obj = {
      "array1": [
        {
          "label": "something1",
          "ref": "option2a"
        },
        {
          "label": "something2",
          "ref": "option2b"
        },
        {
          "label": "something3",
          "ref": "option2a"
        },
        {
          "label": "something4",
          "ref": "option2a"
        },
        {
          "label": "something5",
          "ref": "option2a"
        }
      ],
      "array2": [
        {
          "label": "something6 is the longest label",
          "ref": "option3a"
        },
        {
          "label": "Other",
          "ref": "option3b"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to get the length of the longest label. In this case I would want to return 17. Because the longest label is "somethinglongest" which has a length of 17.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `somethinglongest`'s length is only 16...

Comment: Nice question. Use of **map()**, and `...` **(tripple dot notaion)** to destructure array is really excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight-forward approach:

```js
let obj = {
      "array1": [
        {"label": "something1", "ref": "option2a"},
        {"label": "something2", "ref": "option2b"},
        {"label": "something3", "ref": "option2a"},
        {"label": "something4", "ref": "option2a"},
        {"label": "something5", "ref": "option2a"}
      ],
      "array2": [
        {"label": "something6 is the longest label", "ref": "option3a"},
        {"label": "Other", "ref": "option3b"}
      ]
};

let longest = 0
for (key in obj){
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    for (let x of obj[key]){
        if (x.label.length > longest)
            longest = x.label.length;
    }
}
console.log(longest);
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get it to work with labels that have spaces?

Comment: I am getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'label' in Calculate Your Total

Comment: @Mandalina I'm afraid I cannot help with that as this error is caused by your own code... If you click the "Run code snippet" blue button in the question, it is clear my code works fine.

Comment: Hello again @cybernaut I added on to the question once again, how would this work for an object containing objects and arrays?

Comment: @Mandalina I'm sorry, one question per question! You'll have to ask a new one (you can link it to this one and I'll take a look).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152210/object-containing-arrays-of-objects-and-arrays-of-strings @cybernaut

Answer (score 4):

- Use `.concat()` and `Object.values()` to get a single array having all objects.
- Use `.map()` to an array containing length of strings.
- And finally use `.reduce()` to get the length of longest string.

```js
let data = {
    "array1": [
        {"label": "something1", "ref": "option2a"},
        {"label": "something2", "ref": "option2b"},
        {"label": "something3", "ref": "option2a"},
        {"label": "something4", "ref": "option2a"},
        {"label": "something5", "ref": "option2a"}
    ],
    "array2": [
        {"label": "somethinglongest", "ref": "option3a"},
        {"label": "Other", "ref": "option3b"}
    ]
};

let reducer = arr => [].concat(...Object.values(arr))
                       .map(({ label }) => label.length)
                       .reduce((r, c) => r > c ? r : c);

console.log(reducer(data));
```

Comment: The legibility is helpful here.

Answer (score 4):

Get an array of all the objects inside the sub arrays.

Calculate the max length of the values mapping each value to its length:

```js
var obj = {
  "array1": [{
      "label": "something1",
      "ref": "option2a"
    },
    {
      "label": "something2",
      "ref": "option2b"
    },
    {
      "label": "something3",
      "ref": "option2a"
    },
    {
      "label": "something4",
      "ref": "option2a"
    },
    {
      "label": "something5",
      "ref": "option2a"
    }
  ],
  "array2": [{
      "label": "somethinglongest",
      "ref": "option3a"
    },
    {
      "label": "Other",
      "ref": "option3b"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(Math.max(...Object.values(obj).flat().map(o => o.label.length)));
```

Comment: +1 for the `flat` method. You can do it without reduce `Math.max(...Object.values(obj).flat().map(o => o.label.length))`

Comment: In the hope of being constructive – why perform so many operations in 1 line? Isn't this difficult to grok at first glance or when coming back in the future to adjust?

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser just because I was typing faster and did all in once. But anyone can extract all the variables he wants to :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to iterate through the own properties of the `obj` object and check if the length of each label is longer than the previous longest length.

```js
var obj = {
  "array1": [
    { "label": "something1", "ref": "option2a" },
    { "label": "something2", "ref": "option2b" },
    { "label": "something3", "ref": "option2a" },
    { "label": "something4", "ref": "option2a" },
    { "label": "something5", "ref": "option2a" }
  ], "array2": [ 
    { "label": "somethinglongest", "ref": "option3a" },
    { "label": "Other", "ref": "option3b" }
  ]
}

let longest = 0;

for (key in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key].forEach(item => {
      if (item.label.length > longest) longest = item.label.length;
    })
  }
}

console.log(longest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look for objects and then for the wanted key. This works for an arbitrary depth of data.

```js
function getLongest(object, key) {
    return Object.values(object).reduce((l, v) => {
        if (key in v) return Math.max(l, v[key].length);
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') return Math.max(l, getLongest(v, key));
        return l;    
    }, 0);
}

var data = { array1: [{ label: "something1", ref: "option2a" }, { label: "something2", ref: "option2b" }, { label: "something3", ref: "option2a" }, { label: "something4", ref: "option2a" }, { label: "something5", ref: "option2a" }], array2: [{ label: "somethinglongest", ref: "option3a" }, { label: "Other", ref: "option3b" }] };

console.log(getLongest(data, 'label'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 1 line statement.

```
let maxLen = Math.max(...Object.keys(obj).map((key) => Math.max(...obj[key].map((o) => o.label.length))));
```

> Example on Node REPL

```
> var obj = {
...       "array1": [
...         {
.....           "label": "something1",
.....           "ref": "option2a"
.....         },
...         {
.....           "label": "something2",
.....           "ref": "option2b"
.....         },
...         {
.....           "label": "something3",
.....           "ref": "option2a"
.....         },
...         {
.....           "label": "something4",
.....           "ref": "option2a"
.....         },
...         {
.....           "label": "something5",
.....           "ref": "option2a"
.....         }
...       ],
...       "array2": [
...         {
.....           "label": "somethinglongest",
.....           "ref": "option3a"
.....         },
...         {
.....           "label": "Other",
.....           "ref": "option3b"
.....         }
...       ]
...     }
undefined
>
> Math.max(...Object.keys(obj).map((key) => Math.max(...obj[key].map((o) => o.label.length))))
16
>
```

> Detailed overview

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj);

let maxLens = keys.map((key) => {
    let arr = obj[key];
    return Math.max(...arr.map((o) => o.label.length))
});

let max = Math.max(...maxLens);

console.log(keys);    // [ 'array1', 'array2' ]
console.log(maxLens); // [ 10, 16 ]
console.log(max);     // 16
```

> And here is the example to help you.

```
> Math.max(4, 5, 7)
7
>
> Math.max([4, 5, 7])
NaN
>
> Math.max(...[6, 7])
7
>
> let a = [2, 4, 5]
undefined
>
> a2 = a.map((num) => num ** 2)
[ 4, 16, 25 ]
>
> a3 = a.map((num) => num + 2)
[ 4, 6, 7 ]
>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer! I have updated the question to include labels that have spaces in it. Can you possibly show me how this will work to include the update? I love the walk through.

Comment: So in that case the same code will work but it will also count spaces. Do you want to skip spaces or it is ok? Thank you.